# hibernate - disables MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there a way to disable this during INSERT/DELETE?

Situation:
I have a masterDB and a library1DB and library2DB.

library1DB and library2DB are two separate database but has the same schema because each library must have their own database.  Now we have a masterDB, this is an aggregated version of all the data in all libraries (library1DB and library2DB), still taking note of their respective ids and mapping them to their library id.

Here's the structure of my book model in masterDB?

Book.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long masterId;

@Column
private long id;

@Column
private String title;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "book")
private List<BookCoverHistory> bookCoverHistory;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "LIBRARY_ID")
private Library library;
```

This is all good and well.

However in my BookCoverHistory when I'm inserting a data, I'm getting the exception below.

BookCoverHistory.java

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long masterId;

    @Column
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
    private Book book;

    @Column
    private String desc;
```

Here's the exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`master_db`.`book_cover_history`, CONSTRAINT `FK_10ggatm9ptqayo4naj23329rc` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `book` (`master_id`))
```

So I thought, I just disable the constraints since I'm not very specific to them as I'm just aggregating the data on my libraries to my masterDB and would not do CRUD operations manually but just through the syncing process.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable constraint checking in hibernate, because hibernate shows an errror which was originally thrown by your database.

You are probably using the same database connection for inserting the data. But as you said you have multiple DBs, you need to get a connection/session for your other database. If the table is well defined, you can insert without any reference to other books.

Also, you'd need to remove the joins, since those are only for tables in the same column. You need to join Books and Covers manually, if those tables do not share the same database (and thus session).